# Comparing deviance plots for different loss functions

Tags: python, scikit-learn, decision-tree, loss-function

I'm using the `GradientBoostingRegressor` from Scikit-Learn and want to compare the deviance plots for different loss functions. Say I want to compare the Least Squares Loss and Least Absolute Deviance (LAD) loss. I believe that it's necessary to square the LAD loss (or take the square root of the LS loss), otherwise they would have loss of different powers. But when looking at the Huber loss in the source code, this is not taken into account. To me it seems strange to treat a squared loss the same way as a linear loss.

Does anyone have thoughts on this?